# In Navbar in bootstrap 4 hamburger menu is not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, hamburger-menu

I have written the code in vs code editor but it is not working:

[image: Code image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps if you can share your code in the question (rather than an image of your screen). Simply telling the world that something isn't working doesn't provide us enough information to help you. It is most likely something you have done. You can read more about how to ask a good question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you provide working code in form of pen or fiddle, visit codepen.io or jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Candy</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navlinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navlinks">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tickets</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script> -->
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**you are wrong at**

> data-target="navlinks"

**change to**

> data-target="#navlinks"